# Winking in derived objects using clearmake

Tags: clearcase

Does anyone know the rules for winking in derived objects (DO) when using clearmake?

I got into a situation where a clean compilation resulted in .o and .d files being 5 days old. After investigation I found that a sibling view had the same baseline as me, but hadn't been recompiled since the rebase and these DO's were being winked in to my view.

Will DO's in the team view get winked in to child streams or does it only work with siblings? Further will winking in happen across all views in any hierarchy?

Many thanks

**EDIT :** More specifically I want to know where the DO's are winked in from? Sibling views only? Any view with the same baseline?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shouldn't winked between views, unless the command [`winkin`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_winkin.htm) is called explicitly and/or your are dealing with sharable DOs.

The child stream could get the same DO's if its foundation baseline is the same than the prarent stream, referencing the same versions.

Comment: Can the DO's be winked in from any view on the clearcase server or just within the hierarchy of my view (parents/siblings/children)?

Comment: @DaveWhittingham I believe any view. If by parents/sibling/children you reference the hierarchy of UCM Streams (used by your views), then it has no bearing on DOs.

Answer (score 2):

- It seems you are dealing with shareable DOs
- In order to avoid winkin between views, you can use clearmake -V, which disables any winkin.